# Why doesn't File::Find handle my broken symlink?

Tags: perl, symlink, file-find

I'm using Perl's File::Find module to scan for files, directories, and links.  Among other things, I want the utility I'm writing to report broken (dangling in File::Find's parlance) symbolic links. In theory, this is supported by creating a subroutine to be called whenever a broken link has been found, and calling the `find` method with a hash reference of appropriate values, such as:

```
my %options = (
   wanted            => \&ProcessFile,
   follow            => 1,
   follow_skip       => 2,
   dangling_symlinks => \&Dangling
);

find(\%options, @ARGV);
```

Despite deliberately creating a broken link to test this, File::Find never, ever calls the subroutine `Dangling`. Everything else works except this feature, i.e. the `ProcessFile` sub gets called as expected, links are followed, etc.

Comment: Can you add what your version of Perl is, please?

Answer (score 2):

Created `test.pl` in my home directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Find;

my %options = ( wanted => \&ProcessFile,
                follow => 1,
                follow_skip => 2,
                dangling_symlinks => \&Dangling );

find(\%options, @ARGV);

sub ProcessFile {
  print "ProcessFile ($File::Find::name in $File::Find::dir)\n";
}

sub Dangling {
  my ($name, $dir) = @_;
  print "Dangling ($name in $dir)\n";
}
```

Then:

```
    $ chmod 755 test.pl

    $ mkdir /tmp/findtest
    $ cd /tmp/findtest
    $ ln -s /tmp/doesnotexist linkylink
    $ ~/test.pl .
```

Results in:

```
ProcessFile (. in .)
Dangling (linkylink in ./)
ProcessFile (./linkylink in .)
```

Comment: What version of Perl are you using?  I'm using 5.8.0, and it flat does not work for me.  The Dangling subroutine (which in my code is very similar to yours) is never called.  To test it, I created a directory, linked to it using ln -s, then removed the directory.

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick test to work out what behaviors dangling symlinks exhibit, and it turns out the definition of a symlink is as far as I can make out

1. -l returns true
2. -e returns undef # because -e works on the linked file

So using File::Find::Rule what you appear to be trying to do is relatively simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule ();

my @files = File::Find::Rule->symlink->exec(sub{ !-e $_ })->in('/tmp/test');

print "$_,\n" for @files;
```

This code snippet was able to detect all my broken symlinks that I could tell.

If you want the Test I ran to conclude this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path ();
use Carp       ();

my $testdir = "/tmp/test";

# Generating test

# Making Dirs
dirmk($_)
  for (
    qw(
    /realdir/
    /deleteddir/
    )
  );

#"Touching" some files
generate($_)
  for (
    qw(
    /realfile
    /deletedfile
    /realdir/realfile
    /realdir/deletedfile
    /deleteddir/afile
    )
  );

# Symlink them
{
    lns( '/realfile',            '/realfile_symlink' );
    lns( '/deletedfile',         '/deletedfile_symlink' );
    lns( '/realdir',             '/realdir_symlink' );
    lns( '/deleteddir',          '/deleteddir_symlink' );
    lns( '/realdir/realfile',    '/realdir_realfile_symlink' );
    lns( '/realdir/deletedfile', '/realdir_deletedfile_symlink' );
    lns( '/deleteddir/afile',    '/deleteddir_file' );
}

# Make the deletions
del($_)
  for (
    qw(
    /deletedfile
    /deleteddir/afile
    /realdir/deletedfile
    /deleteddir/
    )
  );

statify($_)
  for (
    '', qw(
    /realfile
    /realfile_symlink
    /deletedfile_symlink
    /realdir
    /realdir_symlink
    /deleteddir_symlink
    /realdir/realfile
    /realdir_realfile_symlink
    /realdir_deletedfile_symlink
    /deleteddir_file
    )
  );

sub statify {
    my $fn = $testdir . shift;
    printf(
        "r: %3s e: %3s s: %3s f: %3s d: %3s l: %3s | %s \n",
        -r $fn || 0,
        -e $fn || 0,
        -s $fn || 0,
        -f $fn || 0,
        -d $fn || 0,
        -l $fn || 0,
        $fn
    );

}

sub generate {
    my $fn = $testdir . shift;
    open my $fh, '>', $fn or Carp::croak("Error Creating $fn $! $@");
    print $fh "This is $fn \n";
    close $fh or Carp::carp("Error on close for $fn $! $@");
    return;
}

sub lns {
    my $x = $testdir . shift;
    my $y = $testdir . shift;
    if ( -e $y ) {
        unlink $y;
    }
    symlink $x, $y or Carp::croak("Error ln $x => $y , $! $@");
}

sub del {
    my $fn = $testdir . shift;
    if ( -f $fn ) {
        unlink $fn;
    }
    if ( -d $fn ) {
        rmdir $fn;
    }
}

sub dirmk {
    my $fn = $testdir . shift;
    File::Path::mkpath($fn);
}
```

And here was the output:

```
r:   1 e:   1 s: 220 f:   0 d:   1 l:   0 | /tmp/test 
r:   1 e:   1 s:  28 f:   1 d:   0 l:   0 | /tmp/test/realfile 
r:   1 e:   1 s:  28 f:   1 d:   0 l:   1 | /tmp/test/realfile_symlink 
r:   0 e:   0 s:   0 f:   0 d:   0 l:   1 | /tmp/test/deletedfile_symlink 
r:   1 e:   1 s:  60 f:   0 d:   1 l:   0 | /tmp/test/realdir 
r:   1 e:   1 s:  60 f:   0 d:   1 l:   1 | /tmp/test/realdir_symlink 
r:   0 e:   0 s:   0 f:   0 d:   0 l:   1 | /tmp/test/deleteddir_symlink 
r:   1 e:   1 s:  36 f:   1 d:   0 l:   0 | /tmp/test/realdir/realfile 
r:   1 e:   1 s:  36 f:   1 d:   0 l:   1 | /tmp/test/realdir_realfile_symlink 
r:   0 e:   0 s:   0 f:   0 d:   0 l:   1 | /tmp/test/realdir_deletedfile_symlink 
r:   0 e:   0 s:   0 f:   0 d:   0 l:   1 | /tmp/test/deleteddir_file
```

Answer (score 1):

I like seeing [`File::Find::Rule`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Find-Rule/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm) in use, but it makes no difference here.

That being said,

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ ln -s a b
$ perl -w -MFile::Find -e'find({wanted=>sub{print"wanted $_\n"},dangling_symlinks=>sub{print"dangling $_[0] in $_\n"},follow=>1},".")'
wanted .
dangling b in .
wanted b
```

works for me.

What's `perl -MFile::Find -e'print"$File::Find::VERSION\n"'`?

#### update

Looking through Perl's RT, I found [#28929: File::Find follow_fast => 1 loses dangling symlink](http://rt.perl.org/rt3/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=28929).  It apparently affects `File::Find` 1.07 and earlier, which is bundled with Perl 5.8.7 and earlier (as well as 5.9.1 and earlier in the 5.9.x development line).

I would suggest you convince your sysadmins to update Perl, or at least a few modules (and add `File::Find::Rule` while they're at it), but failing that, you can make your own [`$PERL5LIB`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#ENVIRONMENT) and place updated modules there.

Comment: Sadly, my company has not made the module File::Find::Rule available.  I tried....

Comment: You could always take the source of File::Fine::Rule and put it in your script.